# Java console input handling

Tags: java, validation, input, console

This is my first question here, I hope it's not too based on opinions. I've searched on the internet for quite a while now, but couldn't find a similar question.
I need to write a Java program that reads commands from the console, validates the input, gets the parameters and passes them on to a different class.
There are some restrictions on what I can do and use (university).

- Only the packages **java.util, java.lang and java.io** are allowed
- Each method can only be 80 lines long
- Each line can only be 120 characters long
- I am not allowed to use System.exit / Runtime.exit
- The **Terminal class** is used to handle user input. `Terminal.readLine()` will read a line from the console, like `Scanner.nextLine()`

I have a fully working program - however my solution will not be accepted because of the way I handle console inputs (`runInteractionLoop()` method too long). I'm doing it like this:

1. The main class has the main method and an "interaction loop" where console inputs are handled. The main method calls the interaction loop in a while loop, with a boolean "quit" as a guardian.

   ```
   private static boolean quit = false;
   ...
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       ...
       while (quit == false) {
           runInteractionLoop();
       }
   }
   ```
2. The interaction loop handles console input. I need to check for 16 different commands - each with their own types of parameters. I chose to work with Patterns and Matchers, because I can use the groups for convenience. Now the problems start - I have never learned how to correctly handle user inputs. What I have done here is, for each possible command, create a new Matcher, see if the input matches, if it does then do whatever needs to be done for this input.

   ```
   private static runInteractionLoop() {
       Matcher m;
       String query = Terminal.readLine;
       m = Pattern.compile("sliding-window (\\d+) (-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?;)*(-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)").matcher(query);
       if (m.matches()) {
           xyz.doSth(Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)), ......);
           ...
           return;
       }
       m = Pattern.compile("record ([a-z]+) (-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)").matcher(query);
       if (m.matches()) {
           xyz.doSthElse(m.group(1), Double.parseDouble(m.group(2)));
           return;
       }
       ...
       if (query.equals("quit")) {
           quit = true;
           return;
       }
       Terminal.printError("invalid input");
   }
   ```

As you can see, doing this 16 times stretches out the method to more than 80 lines (5 lines per input max). It's also obviously very inefficient and to be honest, I'm quite ashamed to be posting this here (crap code). I just don't know how to do this correctly, using only java.util and having some way to quickly get the parameters (e.g. the Matcher groups here).
Any ideas? I would be very grateful for suggestions. Thanks.

**EDIT/UPDATE:**
I have made the decision to split the verification into two methods - one for each half of the commands. Looks ugly, but passes the Uni's checkstyle requirements. **However**, I'd still be more than happy if someone shows me a better solution to my problem - for the future (because I obviously have no idea how to make this prettier, shorter and/or more efficient).

Comment: Do you mean you are not allowed to use java.util.regex?

Comment: @Heri no, I am **allowed** to use all classes in the packages java.util, java.io and java.lang, but only these.

Comment: As it stands right now, I will probably make another method `runInteractionLoop2()` and move half of the validation to that method - but that is ugly as #@$!

Comment: That's not a clear answer. regex is a subpackage of java.util. You may use it or not?

Comment: How exactly do the 16 different possibilities differ?

Comment: @Heri Yes I may. Sorry if I wasn't being clear. Everything in my solution is alright and accepted, except the method length, that is the only problem.
The possibilities are something along the lines of: `<command> (lowercase String|integer|double|String with doubles with ";" delimiter){0,5}`

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could try something painful like this where you separate everything into a chain of method calls:

```
private static runInteractionLoop() {
    Matcher m;
    String query = Terminal.readLine;
    m = Pattern.compile("sliding-window (\\d+) (-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?;)*(-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)").matcher(query);
    if (m.matches()) {
        xyz.doSth(Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)), ......);
        ...
        return;
    } else {
        tryDouble(query, m);
    }
}

Private  static tryDouble(String query, Matcher m) {
    m = Pattern.compile("record ([a-z]+) (-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)").matcher(query);
    if (m.matches()) {
        xyz.doSthElse(m.group(1), Double.parseDouble(m.group(2)));
        return;
    } else {
        trySomethingElse(query, m);
    }
}

Private static trySomethingElse(String query, Matcher m) {
    ...
    if (query.equals("quit")) {
        quit = true;
        return;
    }
    Terminal.printError("invalid input");
}
```

Comment: Yeah, painful is the right word... I'm making it my last option, just add a method for each query that needs more than a one-liner for validation. That'd get me to exactly 80 lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can boil down each possibility to two lines (or three if there must be a closing bracket on a separat line) by delegating the match work to a submethod:

```
if ( Matcher m = matches( query, "sliding-window (\\d+) (-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?;)*(-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)") != null)
    xyz.doSth(Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)), ......);
else if ( Matcher m = matches( query, "record ([a-z]+) (-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)") != null)
    xyz.doSthElse(m.group(1), Double.parseDouble(m.group(2)));
...
else


private Matcher matches( String input, String regexp)
{
    Matcher result = Pattern.compile(regexp).matcher(input);
    if ( result.matches() )
        return result;
    else
        return null;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this looks like a good solution to the problem. I'll try this out later and will report if it works with my Uni's restrictive checkstyle.

Comment: If you are using java8 you could even solve it with a one or two liner if you define first several lookup tables (Minimal: a map between your command string and a corresponding handler)

Comment: Umm... are you sure this works? Since `matches(String input, String regexp)` returns a `Matcher`, what is the boolean value for the if-statement?
Also, I'd be very interested in the Java8 solution :)

Comment: My proposal for lookup tables would involve first a deep analys of the different commands (how can they be distinguesh, and what all have in common, which parameters of which type are expected for which command etc.). And it looks like a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this with an abstract class `CommandValidator`:

```
public abstract class CommandValidator {

    /* getter and setter */

    public Matcher resolveMatcher(String query) {
        return Pattern.compile(getCommand()).matcher(query);
    }

    public abstract String getCommand();

    public abstract void doSth();
}
```

and would implement 16 different CommandValidators for each handler and implement the abstract methods differently:

```
public class IntegerCommandValidator extends CommandValidator {

    @Override
    public String getCommand() {
        return "sliding-window (\\d+) (-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?;)*(-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)";
    }

    @Override
    public void doSth() {
        /* magic here, parameter input the matcher and xyz, or have it defined as field at the class */
        // xyz.doSth(Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)), ......);
    }
}
```

Since you need the matcher in your `CommandValidator` you might set it as field of the class, or just give it into the `doSth()` method.

Then you can instantiate each concrete Validator in a list and iterate through every validator, resolve the matcher and look if it matches:

```
  private static Set<CommandValidator> allConcreteValidators;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      /* */
      allConcreteValidators.add(new IntegerCommandValidator());
      /* */
      while (quit == false) {
        runInteractionLoop();
      }
  }

  private static runInteractionLoop() {
      String query = Terminal.readLine;
      for (CommandValidator validator : allConcreteValidators) {
          if (validator.resolveMatcher(query).matches()) {
              validator.doSth();
          }
      }
  }
```

Of course you could build a lookup method before, if there even is a validator which fits and handle the case that you don't have any validator defined.

Might be a bit over engineered for your exercise. Maybe you can give the command into the constructor of your concrete validators, if they share the same doSth magic as well.
Ofc you should find better names for the classes, because it is not only a validator but something different.

Comment: This is very interesting!! Definitely a bit over-engineered for this exercise, but looks nice and well structured. I like this, thanks!